# ionic5 Capacitor "media scanner plugin" after use File Transfer plugin to download image to photo gallery

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor-plugin

It a ionic5 app build with Cordova Capacitor. There's a function using "File Transfer" plugin to download image to local phone photo gallery. I can success download the image, but it don't show in phone's gallery app(with file browser app can find it). I see there is a Cordova plugin "cordova-plugin-mediascanner", but can not find Capacitor version, Is there a Capacitor plugin? Or other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another plugin "photoLibrary" to solved this:

```js
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/download.php");
fileTransfer.download(uri, 'cdvfile://localhost/temporary/path/to/image.jpg', 
function (entry) {
var targetPath= entry.toURL();
**cordova.plugins.photoLibrary.saveImage(targetPath, "myApp", function** 
(libraryItem) {
  ...
 });
}, function(error) {
 ...
});
```